# Chatter Notification Email - Direct to Community

Tags: email, chatter, community

We are using Chatter in conjunction with a community in Salesforce. When our users get a Chatter notification email, the "View Comment" button within the email takes them to Salesforce, not to the related community. Is there any way to edit the underlying URL of the Chatter notification "View Comment" button?

Thanks,
Rochelle

Comment: Go to the Community Management and then Administration tab and then Emails tab under the Chatter Email Branding section if you click on Preview.  Does the popup Preview email show a link to your Community that is correct or is it Salesforce.com?

Comment: @Jason Yes, it shows the appropriate URL to my community. This is different from what is getting sent out in our Chatter emails though -- that is using our URL to the internal side of Salesforce for Standard users.

Comment: Can you add more details to your question then please?  Who is posting and where are they posting from etc.  More information the better.